# Implementing ViewPager in custom calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a FragmentActivity with 2 tabs. Each tab calls a fragment- Calendar and Converter:

```
public class Calendar extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

//create tabs
}


private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(tab.getPosition()==0)
        {
            CalendarFragment frag = new CalendarFragment();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
        else
        {
            ConverterFragment frag = new ConverterFragment();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        }
    }
..

}
```

In the [Calendar fragment](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/), I would like to implement ViewPager for the Month view so that the user can swipe next/prev when changing the month.

This is the code I have till now. But all this does is display the current month calendar.

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_calendar_view, container, false);

       //set calendar adapter 
       //Code from http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

       context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
       CalendarPagerAdapter adapter = new CalendarPagerAdapter();
       myPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
       myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
       myPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }


   public class CalendarPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

         public int getCount() {
                 return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
         }

         public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
                 Log.d("Object", "Instantiated");
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_calendar_view, null);

                _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
                month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
                year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                calendarView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
                calendarWeek = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendarweek);

                calendarWeek.setAdapter(new CalendarWeekAdapter(context));
                // Initialised
                adapter = new GridCellAdapter(context, R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);

                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);

                return v;
         }

         @Override
         public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
                 ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

         }

         @Override
         public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

         @Override
         public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                 return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

         }

         @Override
         public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

         @Override
         public Parcelable saveState() {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 return null;
         }

         @Override
         public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

     }

}
```

I am stuck here since I do not know how to display prev month calendar when the user swipes left and next month calendar when the user swipes right.

I have tried adding this code to `Object instantiateItem`:

```
 switch(position){
    case 0:
       Log.d("ViewPager", "Prev");
       if (month <= 1)
            {
                month = 12;
                year--;
            }
        else
            {
                month--;
            }
        if (hmonth <= 1)
            {
                hmonth = 12;
                hyear--;
            }
        else
            {
                hmonth--;
            }
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
    break;
    case 2:

       Log.d("ViewPager", "Next");
       if (month > 11)
            {
                month = 1;
                year++;
            }
        else
            {
                month++;
            }
        if (hmonth > 11)
            {
                hmonth = 1;
                hyear++;
            }
        else
            {
                hmonth++;
            }
        setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);

    break;
    }
```

But no swiping happens. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the value of NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS ?

Comment: `private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 100;`

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @JasonHessley, no. I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: Does this: Log.d("Object", "Instantiated"); show up in your your debug log?

Comment: Yes, it does. Have I coded the `Object instantiated` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes touch event listeners don't play well together.  Implementing onClickListenr for CalendarFragment may be stealing the touch event from your PagerAdapter.

------ EDIT -------

If Log.d("Object", "Instantiated"); is showing up in your debug log everytime you swipe, your PagerAdapter is working.  This means that it is a problem with how you are changing the current month to display.

Try this:

```
// put this at the class level of calendarFragment.
Calendar holdTodaysDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());


_calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
_calendar = holdTodaysDate; // Add this line;
_calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, position); // Add this line
month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

This is to reset the calendar to today's date before adding position to it.  The way it is now _calendar is maintaining it's state between views.

Comment: But I need to implement the `onClickListener` to display a dialog on the click of the date.

Comment: If removing it fixes the swipe problem then this problem is solved.  To help you get them working together we will need to see the relevant code.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't fix.

Comment: Thank you so much! That at least got me going somewhere.

Comment: that worked, but it also adds position to the months. That means if it's at position 2, it will add 2 months to the date. So when I scroll, I get October, November, January, April. What is wrong?

Comment: Edited to solve the increment problem described in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

> I am stuck here since I do not know how to display prev month calendar when the user swipes left and next month calendar when the user swipes right.

Assuming `GridCellAdapter` is written properly, this should be happening automatically. `instantiateItem()` will be called for each position, where you create a `GridCellAdapter` suitable for whatever month that position relates to, and you use that `GridCellAdapter` with the `View` you are returning from `instantiateItem()`.

Comment: I am using this calendar: http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/ The GridCellAdapter is written properly. Yet I'm not sure why it's not swiping.